# Qt stream control transmission protocol (sctp)

Tags: qt, qt5.10

I am attempting to run the qt examples multistreamserver & multistreamclient, which rely on the QSctpServer & QSctpSocket.

I receive errors "QSctpSosket does not name a type"
and "invalid use of incomplete type 'class QSctpServer'"

What is going on?

Running Ubuntu 16.04, Qt 5.10.1

Comment: have you added `#include <QSctpSocket>` in header and `QT += network` in `.pro`

Comment: I include all of these lines in my .pro, but i figured it out, answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCTP functionality does not exist in windows... so by default sctp is disabled.

You must configure qt with the -sctp flag and the -static commands, make sure to link any libraries you need as well.