# How to enable making objects from QSctpSocket?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.12

I am attempting to use QSctpServer & QSctpSocket, but I can't make an object from none of these classes.

What is the problem?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Qt version: 5.12.3

I also visited [Qt stream control transmission protocol (sctp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503376/qt-stream-control-transmission-protocol-sctp) but confused about what exactly should I do!

.pro is as follows:

```
QT += core
QT += network
TARGET = TcpServer
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
```

Comment: show your .pro. add `QT += network` to .pro

Comment: I'd have added QT += network to .pro already.

Comment: In [detailed description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsctpsocket.html#details) said this feature is not supported on the Windows platform, but I'm on Ubuntu!!!

Comment: I've included <QSctpSocket> but the problem is I can't define: QSctpSocket *t = ...

Comment: It seems that the Qt version you have has not activated the `libsctp` flag when compiling Qt (check this bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57668), so the solution is to compile Qt by enabling that flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile Qt by enabling -sctp flag solved the problem. After goring to Qt source folder did the following:

```
./configure -sctp
make 
make install
```